# ios - override init method throws method implementation does not match its declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, constructor

Trying to override init method (to create instance with already initialized tag) in class and getting exception. Code sample:

```
@interface DiagnosticsReport : NSObject  {
}
@property NSString *tag;
- (void) initWithTag:(NSString*) tag;
@end

@implementation DiagnosticsReport
- (id) initWithTag:(NSString*) tag {
    if (self = [self init]) {
        _tag = tag;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // default init here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration of method returns `void`, while definition returns `id`. Change both to return `instancetype` and you're good to go.